# iPhone - People picker, is it possible to change the naviagtion bar color and text?

Tags: iphone, background-color, abpeoplepickerview, peoplepicker

A quick iPhone question, I currently use a people picker in my application, I use a black navigation bar in my application but the people picker displays in the default blue color.

I have tried:

```
picker.navigationBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
```

However it still displays in the blue color.

Is it possible to change the color of the navigation bar on the people picker? Or is it always going to be blue as it is a system Modal view?

**EDIT:**

Using the following works for the color:

```
picker.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
```

However using:

```
picker.title = @"MyText";
```

or

```
picker.navigationItem.title=@"MyText";
```

or

```
self.title=@"MyText";
```

Doesn't work, the title always remains as "All Contacts"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The color of a UINavigationBar is controlled by its `tintColor` property.

You can change the color of *all* navigation bars in your app by making a category on `UINavigationBar`.  Just note that all changes you make in a category are applied across all instances of that class in your app.

In your category, in the `init` method, change `self.tintColor`.

Since categories change all instances of a class in your app, it will be trickier to change the text with a category. Instead, try setting the `title` of the target view.

Comment: do you know if apple store accept apps with changed address book color?

Comment: @Fran - I think they did, but I'm not certain.At this point, you're not supposed to use categories like that anymore, since iOS 5 adds new ways of customizing native UI controls.

Answer (score 2):

```
- (void)showNewPersonViewController {
ABNewPersonViewController *picker1 = [[ABNewPersonViewController alloc] init];
picker1.newPersonViewDelegate = self;

UINavigationController *navigation = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:picker1];
navigation.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor brownColor];
[self presentModalViewController:navigation animated:YES];

[picker1 release];
[navigation release];   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

for Changing the color of `UINavigationController`

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:42/256.0 green:60/256.0 blue:80/256.0 alpha:1.0];
```

Changing the text of `UINavigationController`

```
self.text = @"My New text" ;
```

Comment: Thanks, the tintcolor works, but the self.text doesn't, the title on the peoplepicker remains "All Contacts"